# Is it in any way possible to use tsparticles with next.js and ssr?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-particles-js

I am building a customer center for my agency and for performance reasons we rely on ssr. I would really like to implement tsparticles, but after what i think is the correct way to set this up, i get this error:

```
Server Error
Error: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client Components. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component
```

The docs say "Warning: This file must be built for client side usage, SSR is not supported." somewhere in between different framework / library setups, so i don't really know what exactly this applies to.

Here are my files:

ParticlesBackrgound.js:

```
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import particlesConfig from "./config/particles-config";

const ParticlesBackground = () => {
    retun (
        <Particles params={particlesConfig}>

        </Particles>
    )
}

export default ParticlesBackground

particles-config.js:
const particlesConfig = {
    /* coniguraitons */
  }
 
export default particlesConfig
```

page.jsx:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image'

import ParticlesBackground from 'src/app/ParticlesBackground.js';

export default function LandingPage() {
  return (
    <main id="landing-page-wrapper">

      <ParticlesBackground/>

      <h2>
        Customer Center
      </h2>

      <div id="login">
        <button className="strong-hover-shake">Login</button>
      </div>

    </main>
  )
}
```

I also tried to use transpile inside the next.config.js as i saw it in another issue, but that did not change anything

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
    transpilePackages: ['tsparticles'],
    /* Your Next.js config */
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 "Warning: This file must be built for client side usage, SSR is not supported."
```

***As per the above warning, it clearly tells that library doesn't supports Server-side rendering. If you read here on library tsParticles : Its compatible with React.js, NextJS not mentioned.***

*This library is browser based, you need browser to render it.*

https://particles.js.org/docs/index.html

If you read here **react-tsparticles** is official tsParticles `ReactJS component`.
https://github.com/tsparticles/react#readme

- So you have to implement it as client-side component.
- You can wrap childrens in your ParticlesBackrgound.js

**Here is a example code I made by using official documentations** :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tsparticles#options-object

https://github.com/tsparticles/react#readme

**Folder Structure :**

```
projectName
├── .gitignore
├── jsconfig.json
├── next.config.js
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── postcss.config.js
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── next.svg
│   └── vercel.svg
├── README.md
├── src
│   └── app
│       ├── api
│       ├── comp
│       │   ├── ParticlesBackrgound.js
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       ├── globals.css
│       ├── layout.js
│       ├── page.js
│       ├── part
│       │   └── page.js
└── tailwind.config.js
```

Don't forget to install : `npm i tsparticles tsparticles-slim` as this will used to load `loadSlim` or `loadFull`.

tsparticles to import `loadFull` & tsparticles-slim for `loadSlim`

**Read here about loadSlim :** `https://particles.js.org/docs/functions/tsParticles_Slim_Bundle.index.loadSlim.html`
*Loads the slime bundle with all plugins needed for running the tsParticles Slim package.*

**Read here about loadFull:** https://particles.js.org/docs/functions/tsParticles_Full_Bundle.index.loadFull.html
*Loads the full bundle with all plugins needed for running the tsParticles package.*

- ***If you want to implement it on a specific page :***

I have made a `folder part` which has page.js, this page will be available on route

`http://localhost:3000/part`

This page has Particles Background.

**page.js**    `loc\src\app\part\page.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import ParticlesBackrgound from '../comp/ParticlesBackrgound'
const page = () => {
    return (
        <ParticlesBackrgound>
            <h1>Page with particles background !</h1>
            <div>
                Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit, debitis nostrum est et impedit consequatur id quod autem a omnis unde ipsum, odio sunt nesciunt officia aliquam. Officiis atque ipsa corrupti qui similique distinctio in repellendus sequi libero cum assumenda, earum hic odio, quo laudantium. Nulla doloribus tempore sint amet.
            </div>
        </ParticlesBackrgound>
    )
}

export default page
```

- ***If you add it on layout it will be visible throughout the website.***

**layout.js :**

```
<html lang="en">
  <body className={inter.className}>
    <ParticlesBackrgound>
      {children}
    </ParticlesBackrgound>
  </body>
</html >
```

**ParticlesBackrgound.js**

**Don't forget to add your particles config, by using prop** `options`. `options = {your config}`

```
'use client'
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import Particles from "react-tsparticles";
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import { loadSlim } from "tsparticles-slim";


const ParticlesBackrgound = ({ children }) => {
    const particlesInit = useCallback(async engine => {
        console.log(engine);
        await loadSlim(engine);

        // LOAD ANY ONE 
        // await loadFull(engine);
    }, []);

    const particlesLoaded = useCallback(async container => {
        await console.log(container);
    }, []);


    return (

        <>

            <Particles
                id="tsparticles"
                init={particlesInit}
                loaded={particlesLoaded}

                options={your config}

            />
            {children}
        </>



    )
}

export default ParticlesBackrgound
```

**Don't forget to add this under in your** `particlesConfig` :

```
fullScreen: {
    enable: true,
    zIndex: -1

    // IMPORTANT
},
```

**Particles Config** :
I have passed this options directly (options ={below code}), you may make necessary changes wherever required.

```
{
    fullScreen: {
        enable: true,
        zIndex: -1
        // IMPORTANT
    },
    background: {
        color: {
            value: "#0d47a1",
        },
    },
    fpsLimit: 120,
    interactivity: {
        events: {
            onClick: {
                enable: true,
                mode: "push",
            },
            onHover: {
                enable: true,
                mode: "repulse",
            },
            resize: true,
        },
        modes: {
            push: {
                quantity: 4,
            },
            repulse: {
                distance: 200,
                duration: 0.4,
            },
        },
    },
    particles: {
        color: {
            value: "#ffffff",
        },
        links: {
            color: "#ffffff",
            distance: 150,
            enable: true,
            opacity: 0.5,
            width: 1,
        },
        move: {
            direction: "none",
            enable: true,
            outModes: {
                default: "bounce",
            },
            random: false,
            speed: 6,
            straight: false,
        },
        number: {
            density: {
                enable: true,
                area: 800,
            },
            value: 80,
        },
        opacity: {
            value: 0.5,
        },
        shape: {
            type: "circle",
        },
        size: {
            value: { min: 1, max: 5 },
        },
    },
    detectRetina: true,
}
```

Read More at : https://particles.js.org/docs/classes/tsParticles_Engine.Options_Classes_Options.Options.html

- ***If there are any doubts, please leave a comment.***

Comment: Thank you for your help!
In general i think this works, however, i dont get the <ParticleBackground></ParticleBackground> element to be rendered correctly. I want to implement it in a specific page and not use it throughout the whole webapp via the layout file (where it also somehow wasn't rendered correctly). I placed it inside my pages <main> tag to wrap around any elements inside there, but it just cancels these out and i only get the <main> styling. I also tried different z-indexes, none of them worked. Using inspection tools, i can see that <div id=tsparticles> is definetly there

Comment: **Please take a look at the answer**, 
- I have added particles config (it might help you understand where to place that fullscreen key) & also added code to use  `<ParticleBackground>` in a specific page.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! I also watched a video on yt where your 'options' keyword was 'params' instead, i think this was the biggest remaining issue.